# Problem in React typing text in a field text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is how I have the code to save the changes

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  let { Nombre, value } = e.target; 
  setState({ ...state, [Nombre]: value });
};
```

And in the text field I have this: The problem here is when put the field "Value", when I give the `value="Nombre"` it makes it impossible to write in the text field.

```
<Form.Group>
  <Form.Label style={{textAlign:"left"}}>Nombre</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control
    type="text"
    placeholder="Nombre"
    name="Nombre"
    value="Nombre"
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: `let {name, value} = e.target; 
setState({...state,[name]: value})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that you are not destructuring the correct event property to update state.

## Solution

Destructure the `name` and `value` event properties. You'll also want to be in the habit of using [functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to update the state and avoid issues related to stale state enclosures.

Example:

```
const handleChange = (e) => { 
  const { name, value} = e.target; 
  setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    [name]: value
  }));
};
```